# Wordpress sorting by meta_value issue

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is my code:

```
<?php 
global $post; 
$path = $post->post_name;

$types = [
    "butiker"      => "butik",
    "restauranger" => "restaurang",
    "service"      => "service",
    "cafeer"       => "cafe"
];

$meta_value = $types[$path];

$posts = get_posts([
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'Butik',
    'meta_key'       => 'valj_typ',
    'meta_value'     => $meta_value
]);

if( $posts ): ?>

<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
                          setup_postdata( $post )
                ?>

                <div class="stores">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="img-wrapper">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                        </div>
                        <h2>
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h2>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This worked fine when I only had the choice to do 1 argument per post, however I want to be able to tag my posts with multiple choices, like butik & service, and now it breaks. I'm assuming it's because my loop checks if the argument matches with

```
$posts = get_posts([
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'Butik',
    'meta_key'       => 'valj_typ',
    'meta_value'     => $meta_value
]);
```

But I want a post to get listed when having two arguments in the array.

Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a meta_query to use multiple keys. Not sure how your `post_name` is in this case, but you should be able to get `$meta_value` & `$meta_value2` from it.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'valj_typ',
        'value' => $meta_value
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'valj_typ',
        'value' => $meta_value2
    ),
);
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but how would I use that? Could you place that in my existing code?

Comment: `$posts = get_posts([
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'Butik',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'valj_typ',
        'value' => $meta_value
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'valj_typ',
        'value' => $meta_value2
      ),
  )
]);`

Comment: You can read more about meta queries at the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: A slight missunderstanding.

It's the "value" that is coming as an array. So I want to compare all items in the "value" array to $meta_value, any clue?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want, how does an example of the "value" array look like?

Comment: Well basicly: $posts = get_posts([
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'Butik',
    'meta_key'       => 'valj_typ',
    'meta_value'     => $meta_value
]);

This gets all posts where meta_value = my post option. Before I had checkbox in the post settings, where I only could select 1 option, such as "service". 

However now I got alternative boxes and I can check more than 1 option, so I guess my meta_value = option1, option2 and such. 

My code can not compare the result because it does not have only 1 alternative. So I need to somehow check if one of the meta_values fit.

Comment: $meta_value = $types[$path]; this sets meta_value to one paremeter, which it should. However, the 'meta_value' that comes from my wordpress is probably option1, option2, hence why it doesnt loop. Because right now it might say theoretically: 'meta_value' => 'service' which it will fail on, i need something like 'meta_value[1] or meta_value[2] => 'service', because I got two arguments.. Do you undersntad?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78913/discussion-between-codehiker-and-hdk).

Comment: Summary: Instead of using multiple keys like you wrote above, I need it to use multiple values that compares with the key